# How to install Docker Desktop to windows machine that has no internet connection

Tags: windows, docker, containers, offline

I need to install Docker Desktop to a Windows 10 machine that has no internet connection.

I found that there is a tool named "docker toolbox on windows".

Before trying this old product I would like to learn is it possible to install "docker desktop" in an offline environment (Windows 10)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the static builds found at [download.docker.com/win](https://download.docker.com/win/static/stable/x86_64/).

Comment: Please avoid asking questions in answers, even if they are rhetoric or didactical. It just risk being accidentally flagged as "not-an-answer".

Comment: @Yunnosch, thanks for the advice. I have edited my response. I hope imperatives are ok :D

Comment: Sorry, it is a pet peeve of mine that I do not like those "try this, it may help, ..." answers either. But at least they do not risk being flagged. And it is only my opinion. Try something more assertive. That is possible ieven if you have doubts on whether you identified the problem correctly. Like "In case your problem is caused by .... then the solution would be to ... because ....". That is even possible for those who cannot ask clarification questions in comments. The "because ...", obviously followed by as detailed an explanation as you can manage, is what might get upvotes....

Comment: Hmm, I realise that in this case defining the problem and giving an explanation of the solution is hard. Take above as a general recommendation.

Comment: Imperatives in answers are usually fine. The helpfulness of a decent answer outweighs any risk of reading like rudely ordering people around. Good style to think about the "tone" of your phrasings. I think you get the idea of a good answer. Oh by the way, you do of course know the really helpful [answer] description. Or maybe not, I see that you did not find the time yet to take the guided [tour]. It is nice, try it.

Comment: @Yunnosch, that's fine. I agree my comment is a suggestion and not an answer. The fact of the matter is I don't know if the binaries at the link will work as I have not tested them. I know exactly the problem, but without testing the binaries I don't really know if they are the solution to the OP's problem. I was just trying to provide some guidance since there has been a lack of comments or answers. Unfortunately my level is so low I cannot make a comment to other posts.

Comment: [edit] that as an explanation into the answer and even I (with my non-existing undestanding of the matter) will read that as a helpful answer.

Comment: Be careful with describing your post as a comment. If that is taken seriously you get dangerously close again to "not an answer". I am convinced that your contribution already is an answer. It can just become a nicely more helpful/insightful one.